# How to convert an array of objects into key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 var contacts = [
    { account: "Acme", firstName: "John", lastName: "Snow" },
    { account: "Metal Industries", firstName: "Ted", lastName: "Smith" },
    { account: "Acme", firstName: "Sara", lastName: "Butler" },
    { account: "HiTech Corp", firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { account: "HiTech Corp", firstName: "Arnold", lastName: "Williams" },
    { account: "Metal Industries", firstName: "Jessica", lastName: "Westcoat" },
    { account: "Acme", firstName: "Kyle", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { account: "HiTech Corp", firstName: "Jason", lastName: "Fernandez" }
  ];
```

The  goal is to get this output:

```
  result =  {
    "Acme": ["John Snow", "Kyle Johnson", "Sara Butler"],
    "HiTech Corp": ["Arnold Williams", "Jason Fernandez", "Sam Johnson"],
    "Metal Industries": ["Jessica Westcoat", "Ted Smith"]
  }
```

My function below is not returning the array of values and only returns the last value

```
  const convertArrayToObject = (array, key) => {
    const initialValue = {}
    return array.reduce((obj, item) => {
        return {...obj,[item[key]]: item,}
    }, initialValue)
  }
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stlN9.png)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, just missing that when you set up the object in the resultant array, you need to set it as an array - in this script that would be `[k]: [v]` and not `[k]: v`

```js
var contacts = [
    { account: "Acme", firstName: "John", lastName: "Snow" },
    { account: "Metal Industries", firstName: "Ted", lastName: "Smith" },
    { account: "Acme", firstName: "Sara", lastName: "Butler" },
    { account: "HiTech Corp", firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { account: "HiTech Corp", firstName: "Arnold", lastName: "Williams" },
    { account: "Metal Industries", firstName: "Jessica", lastName: "Westcoat" },
    { account: "Acme", firstName: "Kyle", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { account: "HiTech Corp", firstName: "Jason", lastName: "Fernandez" }
  ];


const convertArrayToObject = (array, key) => {
  const initialValue = {}
  return array.reduce((obj, item) => {
    let k = item[key], v=item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName;
    if (obj[k]) obj[k].push(v);
    else obj = { ...obj, [k]: [v] }
    return obj
  }, initialValue)
}

console.log(convertArrayToObject(contacts, 'account'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var contacts = [
    { account: "Acme", firstName: "John", lastName: "Snow" },
    { account: "Metal Industries", firstName: "Ted", lastName: "Smith" },
    { account: "Acme", firstName: "Sara", lastName: "Butler" },
    { account: "HiTech Corp", firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { account: "HiTech Corp", firstName: "Arnold", lastName: "Williams" },
    { account: "Metal Industries", firstName: "Jessica", lastName: "Westcoat" },
    { account: "Acme", firstName: "Kyle", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { account: "HiTech Corp", firstName: "Jason", lastName: "Fernandez" }
  ];

const convertArrayToObject = (array, key) => {
    const initialValue = {}
    array.forEach((obj, item) => {
        initialValue[obj[key]] = initialValue[obj.account] || []
        initialValue[obj[key]].push(`${obj.firstName} ${obj.lastName}`)
    })
    return initialValue
}

console.log(convertArrayToObject(contacts, 'account'))
```